# Argument "selfcontained" deprecated in htmlwidgets::saveWidget()

Tags: html, r, plotly, htmlwidgets

I keep getting `[WARNING] Deprecated: --self-contained. use --embed-resources --standalone` when saving a plotly plot as a self-contained html widget, using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(..., selfcontained = TRUE)`.

I can't figure out how to use "embed-resources" or "standalone" as arguments in the function. This just recently started, wondering if anyone else has had this warning occur, or knows the proper arguments to use for this. Updated RStudio and the package, but the warning persists.

Using R 4.2.1, RStudio 2022.07.2+576 "Spotted Wakerobin", `htmlwidgets` 1.5.4.

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

fig <- plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(partial_bundle(fig), file = "plotly.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
utils::browseURL("plotly.html")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with plotly v4.10.1 and htmlwidgets v1.5.4 and RStudio
2022.07.1 Build 554. I left an example above. However, here you can find a [related issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2382). The warning seems to be raised by [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7331). Maybe a new pandoc version is shipped with the latest RStudio installer?

Comment: That's a Pandoc change in version 2.19.  You can see what version you're using with `htmlwidgets:::pandoc_available(); htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$version`.  I think RStudio distributes version 2.18, but they may have updated, or you may have installed it separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a Pandoc change in version 2.19. You can see what version you're using with `htmlwidgets:::pandoc_available(); htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$version`. I think RStudio distributes version 2.18, but they may have updated, or you may have installed it separately.

The Pandoc change log is here:  https://pandoc.org/releases.html .

I don't think there's any way to fix that other than editing the `htmlwidgets` source.  Maybe this will be fixed in the next release?

EDITED to add:  This change has been handled in `rmarkdown` for a while, but `htmlwidgets` was calling Pandoc directly.  The next release (1.6.0) of `htmlwidgets` will fix it by letting `rmarkdown` handle the call.  This should also future-proof it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I've since found a workaround to produce a standalone `.html` file with no "files" folder: Set your working directory to where you'd like to output the `.html`, Then write your widget (`fig`, here) to the working directory:

```
setwd(myplotdir)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(fig),
                            paste0("./", plot.name),
                        selfcontained = TRUE)
setwd(myoriginalwd)
```

This results in a standalone `.html` for me, interestingly.